# Flutter How can I get progress status of uploading file to google drive by using google drive api?

Tags: flutter, upload, google-drive-api, flutter-web, progress

I am using [google_apis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) v3 to upload a file to drive. How can I get the progress percentage of uploading status through the Google Drive API library? And also how can I cancel the uploading file?

The sample source code is as below.

```
  Future<File> uploadFile(
      GoogleAuthClient googleAuthClient, FileUpload fileUpload) async {
    final DriveApi driveApi = driveDataProvider.getDriveApi(googleAuthClient);

    final Stream<List<int>> mediaStream =
        Future.value(fileUpload.data).asStream().asBroadcastStream();

    Media media = Media(mediaStream, fileUpload.size);

    File createdFile = await driveApi.files.create(fileUpload.file,
        uploadMedia: media, uploadOptions:  UploadOptions.resumable;);

    return createdFile;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```js
int byteCount = 0;
Stream<List<int>> mediaStream = file.openRead().transform(
   StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(handleData: (data, sink) {
        byteCount += data.length;
        //add a callback function here.
        // callback(byteCount);
        sink.add(data);
      }, handleError: (error, stackTrace, sink) {
        //Handle error
      }, handleDone: (sink) {
        sink.close();
      },
   ),
);
```

Comment: I can confirm this method works.

Answer (score 0):

@Werner Scholtz answer should be accepted. I just want to record here how to integrate this approach when creating a google drive Media type of file:

```
var media = drive.Media(
    file.openRead().transform(
          StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
            handleData: (data, sink) {
              log('Something');
              bytesUploaded += data.length;
              sink.add(data);
            },
            handleError: (error, stackTrace, sink) {},
            handleDone: (sink) {
              log('Something done');
              sink.close();
            },
          ),
        ),
    totalBytes);
```

I uploaded it with:

```
var response = await driveApi.files.create(driveFile, uploadMedia: media);
```